# Retrieve travel times from HERE without reoptimizing waypoint order

Tags: here-api, here-routing

How would we pass in existing waypoints to get estimated arrival times WITHOUT reoptimizing the existing order of the waypoint list?  This is needed when the customer requirements mean we have to uses a sub-optimal route, or when changes require manually restacking a day.  Example: The program says that the optimal order is stops A, B, C.  But the customer calls and we now have to make our stops in the order A, C, B.  How can we get the new travel times/arrival times without restacking back to A, B, C?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to find the best optimize order for your set of waypoints, you just need to make a simple routing request with the **HERE Routing API v8** and use the [`via`](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/dev_guide/topics/use-cases/via.html) keyword.

```
curl -X GET \
// replace all {text} by your datas
'https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?origin={START_LATITUDE},{START_LONGITUDE}&transportMode=car&destination={ARRIVAL_LATITUDE},{ARRIVAL_LONGITUDE}&via={CLIENT_A_LATITUDE},{CLIENT_A_LONGITUDE}&via={CLIENT_B_LATITUDE},{CLIENT_B_LONGITUDE}&via={CLIENT_C_LATITUDE},{CLIENT_C_LONGITUDE}&return=polyline,summary&apiKey={YOUR_API_KEY}'
```

it is important to note that there is a maximum limit :

> The maximum number of waypoints including the start point and end point is 120 without traffic and 50 with traffic. If the routing mode pedestrian is used, the distance between each two of the waypoints must not be greater than 5km.

Here provide additional information in the [documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-waypoints/dev_guide/topics/key-concepts.html).